# When i run android application to google Map after click on button My AVD is not compatible?

Tags: android

When i am run my Android App My AVD manger is not compatible to run my android application always it terminated  my application how to slove it.

Error are Following.

1---Installation error: Unknown failure

2---Please check logcat output for more details.

3----could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

What kind of Avd is compatible with Google Api.
I created Application with Google Api

Answer (score 0):

Create an AVD as shown below

[image]

Here the Target API Level should be according to your application target. Make sure that the build target of your application is also the same. You can set the build target as follows.
1. right click your application in Eclipse
2. Select Properties=>Android
3. Now select the same Google API of the target platform

[image]

Now run your application on the Emulator. Hope it will help you. :)